# pass on list from .cs to .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to display a list with details which I have created in my code behind. But I am getting undefined in the console. Why does that happen?

cs:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<Person> persons { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person() { name = "Tom" };
        Person p2 = new Person() { name = "Ed" };
        List<Person> lijst = new List<Person>();
        lijst.Add(p1);
        lijst.Add(p2);
        persons = lijst;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

aspx:

```
<script>
    var persons = '<%= persons%>'
    var length = persons.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        person = persons[i];

        console.log(person.name);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is javascript not having idea about your C# class and it's properties. You may need to convert or serialize it to a known type like string, xml or json etc..

try something like below

You can have method return comma separated person names from class property

```
    public string GetPersonNames
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(",", persons.Select(p => p.name));
        }
    }
```

in your aspx you can get person names and split by `'`

```
<script>
        var persons = '<%= GetPersonNames%>';
</script>
```

Or try below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var persons = '<%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(persons)%>';
    persons = JSON.parse(persons);
    var length = persons.length;
    alert(length);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var person = persons[i];
        alert(person.name);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, code in .cs

```
 Person p1 = new Person() { name = "Tom" };
        Person p2 = new Person() { name = "Ed" };
        List<Person> lijst = new List<Person>();
        lijst.Add(p1);
        lijst.Add(p2);
        persons = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lijst);
```

javascript in aspx

```
var persons = eval('<%= persons%>');
    //this will show "Tom"
    alert(persons[0].name);
```